# merging 2 virtual hard disks on a cloud server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, partition, cloud

I have a cloud server based on Windows Server 2008 r2, with 2 hard disks, one with O.S. installed on it, the other one is empty.

Both the disk have 30GB of space. The first one is almost full and I would like to merge the 2 to have only one disk.

Is that possibile?

I have tried with AOMEI software, but I can only resize the main disk. I see no option to merge the 2.

I suppose it's because the main disk ha operting system on it, or what?

Can this merge be done ro not?

The hosting provider told me about a paging file, but after few reaserches on internet, I do not think it's the proper way to follow.

Any suggestion?

Thank you very much.

EDIT
I have added a screenshot of the disk situation

[disks situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I40s.jpg)

Comment: Convert both disks to dynamic and then create a large spanning volume. But, single 60Gb disk is more effective here, so I'd prefer to instead have second 60Gb, migrate there and then retire former 30 Gb.

Comment: If this is a cloud system (which cloud, BTW?!?) then those are most likely virtual disks; ask your hosting provider to remove the second disk and increase the size of the first one.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Thanks for your hint. Just a newbie question: what do you mean for "convert to dynamic"?

Comment: @Massimo Massimo, I'd like to think you are italian, given your name. Well then, you should be familiar with Aruba. The cloud server is an Aruba Cloud Pro server.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov ok I have read something about dynamic disks. If I convert the main disk, where the O.S. is installed, I won't be able to reboot the o.s. again. I cannot do it. I would loose the softwares installed on it.

Comment: I have added a screenshot to my question.

Comment: @Aptivus you've mislead us :) that isn't two 30 GB disks, that is one 60 Gb disk which is partitioned into two. Be prepared, **absolutely any** way to join them will require OS reboot, maybe not a just one reboot, and will have the risk of losing everythng. So if this is concern, you have to do backups. Ask your virtual infrastructure provider if and how you do the whole disk backup (and recovery), and store the whole disk image. You'll need, well, 60 Gb of space. Then, after this, you'll be able to revert things back to current situation from that image any try infinitely many times.

Comment: @Aptivus, yes, I'm familiar with Aruba, and I really don't like it; anyway, luckily for you this situation doesn't require their intervention. Just see my answer and extend your C: volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not two disks, they are two partitions on the same disk; this makes things a lot simpler.

You don't need to convert the disk to a dynamic disk (although this would absolutely not involve any data loss, you are misleaded here; converting a disk from basic to dynamic is a completely safe operation; it's the reverse that requires deleting all volumes on it).

Simply delete the last partition on the disk (volume E:), then right-click on volume C: and select the option to extend it on the empty space you just freed.

Comment: You nailed it! THANK YOU VERY MUCH! Done and running like charm!